# How do i stop a particular ruby daemons?

Tags: ruby, linux, daemon

For the daemons' options :multiple => true , so, It allows me to start multiple instance of background process.

now, when run command stop it stop all background processes, How can i stop them individually?

Note: I know we can kill by pid but i want the ticker to at_exit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `at_exit` code should still execute provided you use a suitable signal when killing the process. e.g. if you use `SIGINT` rather than `SIGKILL`

```
Process.kill('SIGINT', pid)
```